# Sorting data file by number of vowels

Tags: java

Sort all words by comparing the number of vowels that each word contains. The
word with the fewest number of vowels would come first. If you have more than one word with the same number of vowels, that group would be sorted alphabetically.

I believe that I have most of the project completed, I just don't know why it's not working.

```
public class Word implements Comparable<Word> {
    private String word;

    public Word(String s) {
        word = s;
    }

    private int numVowels() {
        String vowels = "AEIOUaeiou";
        int vowelCount = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < vowels.length(); i++) {
            if ((vowels.charAt(i) == 'a') || (vowels.charAt(i) == 'e') || (vowels.charAt(i) == 'i') || (vowels.charAt(i) == 'o') || (vowels.charAt(i) == 'u')) {
                return vowelCount;
            }
        }
        return vowelCount;
    }

    public int compareTo(Word rhs) {
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            if ((word.charAt(i) == 'a') || (word.charAt(i) == 'A')) {
                System.out.println(word);
            } else if ((word.charAt(i + 1) == 'e') || (word.charAt(i + 1) == 'E')) {
                System.out.println(word);
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return word;
    }
}
```

I think my error is in the `compareTo` method. I'm not sure. Would anyone be able to help me?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what is supposed to happen? I fixed one method but i don't know about the second method sorry. Maybe someone else knows :)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

First of all, try not to post your Homework on here. Your `numVowels()` method is wrong too.

```
private int numVowels() //FIXED METHOD
{
    String vowels = "AEIOUaeiou";
    int vowelCount = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < vowels.length(); i++)
    {
        if((vowels.charAt(i) == 'a') || (vowels.charAt(i) == 'e')  || (vowels.charAt(i) == 'i') || (vowels.charAt(i) == 'o') || (vowels.charAt(i) == 'u') || (vowels.charAt(i) == 'A') || (vowels.charAt(i) == 'E') || (vowels.charAt(i) == 'I') || (vowels.charAt(i) == 'O') || (vowels.charAt(i) == 'U'))      
        {
            return vowelCount; //Will return lowercase AND capital vowels :)
        }
    }
    return vowelCount;
}
```

Your original code only searched for lowercase 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', and 'u'. I added capitals to your if statement ('A', 'E' etc)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with posting homework questions here.  Second, your method is useless since you will always return zero, with a fixed set of data.

Comment: @Makoto how do you fix this, then?

Comment: You may refer to my posted answer for a solution.

Comment: code will work, but we should use collection for better performance.. agree with @Makoto

Answer (score 2):

First - I didn't realize that `Word` was your custom class.  That said...there's a lot of flaws with it.

Your `compareTo` method is really, effectively, only comparing two Strings together.  What you want to do is something like this:

```
public int compareTo(Word other) {
    return word.compareTo(other.getWord());
}
```

The reason for this is that [`String implements Comparable<String>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

Now, if this isn't what you're going for (and I'm really not sure *what* that exactly is), then you may look into comparing the number of vowels two `Word` instances have.

```
public int compareTo(Word other) {
    return word.numVowels() - other.numVowels();
}
```

The above will return a positive value if the current `Word` has more vowels than the `Word` being compared to, a negative value if there are less, or zero if the vowels are equivalent.

Next, your `numVowels()` method is completely broken.  Look at what you're iterating across:  `vowels`.  The `vowels` String is *always* a constant value.  It's **never** going to change - there are exactly ten vowels, five lower case, and five upper case.

What you want to do is check your ***`word`*** field against the set of vowels.

Here's a better* solution:  use a `Set<Character>` - you get constant look up time for them all.

```
Set<Character> vowelSet = new HashSet<Character>() {{
        add('a');
        add('A');
        add('e');
        add('E');
        add('i');
        add('I');
        add('o');
        add('O');
        add('u');
        add('U');
}};
```

Then, all you have to do in your loop is this:

```
int count = 0;
for(char c : word.toCharArray()) {
    if(vowelSet.contains(c)) {
        count++;
    }
}
return count;
```

<sup>*It doesn't take into account that Y is sometimes a vowel.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```
if((vowels.charAt(i) == 'a') || (vowels.charAt(i) == 'e')  || (vowels.charAt(i) == 'i') || (vowels.charAt(i) == 'o') || (vowels.charAt(i) == 'u') || (vowels.charAt(i) == 'A') || (vowels.charAt(i) == 'E') || (vowels.charAt(i) == 'I') || (vowels.charAt(i) == 'O') || (vowels.charAt(i) == 'U'))   
    {
        vowelCount++;
    }
```

You were previously returning 0 when you returned vowelCount. You need to increment vowelCount when you find vowels and then return it after you're done looping. You also need to check for upper case vowels and not just lower case vowels to get an accurate count.

Your compareTo method is not even close to correct...

Comment: You're returning too soon.  You want to *count* the vowels first, *then* return.

Comment: Thanks for catching that, that was my point in the original post, I just missed deleting the return from the actual code. I edited it

Comment: Glad you did.  Now, you have the same issue with the previous answer:  you're only ever comparing against ten vowels, so you will only ever count up to ten.

Comment: I disagree with you here, if you have a word, it will loop through the word and return the number of vowels in that word. Every time in the loop it checks that char and determines if its a vowel. If it is, then your vowel count is incremented. Can you explain to me why you say it will only ever count to ten?

Comment: O i see, you are saying because he has already assigned a word in the method to vowels rather than passing a parameter or something… how would you suggest I edit that to explain that? I feel I answered his question of determining how many vowels are in a string…He is just making the mistake of hardcoding that string to a set value

Comment: @Makoto how do I implement this?

Comment: You can refer to my answer above.  You again only compare against vowels, which is a bit disturbing - you don't even check `word` which may be full of consonants.